# Why does the IDE say: parameter type mismatch: array is not assignable

Tags: android, c, android-studio, java-native-interface

I am writing some JNI code in Android Studio and I get the same error in the IDE over and over again:

```
parameter type mismatch: array is not assignable
```

It is always the same similar situation like this:

```
void testB(uint8_t buff[4]) {
   //some code
}

void testA() {
    uint8_t buff[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };     
    testB(buff);  //buff is underlined red and says: parameter type mismatch: array is not assignable
}
```

so on the line `testB(buff)` buff is underlined in red and shows the above error on hover

The code compiles and runs fine though. Is this a bug in the IDE, or am I doing something wrong here. Can I get rid of this annyoing error?

**UPDATE:** I got my answer from the comments. Thanks Ian Abbott, Lundin & juanchopanza!
I will wait a bit for someone to write a comprehensive answer, and if none appears I will answer this for completion myself later using those comments as basis.

Comment: The error is for which line? It must be written before or after the error.

Comment: See the comment in the last line

Comment: Which compiler are you using in the IDE and which do you use otherwise? Which flags are you using?

Comment: I'm using defaults of Android-Studio sorry. For not being more specific. But I also don't see the flags being important here as it compiles fine. The IDE Editor is the one who is complaining.
Android Studio is 1.5.1

Comment: Your code is valid, but maybe the IDE is trying to prevent a mistake. Change `testB` signature to `void testB(uint8_t* buff)`. Because that is what it really is.

Comment: You need to use `testB(uint8_t* buff)`

Comment: Ok, so the `testB(uint8_t[4] buff)` is merely a hint about what should be this functions input, but is not enforced, is that the reason the compiler is showing an error, to warn me about this potential false assumption?

Comment: @Torge Don't listen to these comments, they are incorrect. `void testB(uint8_t[4] buff)` is 100% equivalent to `void testB(uint8_t* buff)`, the former is merely more readable. This has nothing to do with the mentioned compiler error. In fact, nothing in the posted code has anything to do with that error.

Comment: @Torge I am speculating, but sometimes people who are not familiar with the stranger parts of C's syntax think such a function would make a local copy of the array and/or only compile with arrays of the right length. The fact that the function will accept any `uint8_t*` makes these assumptions dangerous, and the IDE tries to prevent this. I don't allow `foo(int a[N]);` in my own coding conventions but some people like to have the "hint" as a form of documentation.

Comment: @juanchopanza The IDE should hopefully not do jack with the code. The compiler on the other hand, is not allowed to prevent this code from compiling, it is perfectly fine C. There is no type mismatch.

Comment: @Lundin I never said there was a type mismatch or that the code is invalid. Quite the contrary. I am pointing out reasons why an IDE could flag a warning or error.

Comment: @Torge Out of interest, does changing the formal parameter to `uint8_t* buff` "fix" the "error" flagged by the IDE?

Comment: @Ian, yes. The error is gone.

Comment: @Torge Just to be absolutely clear: **your code is perfectly valid C**. And I would add that the error your IDE is showing is quite misleading. It might be worth reporting that to the vendor.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes I understood. Even though I now think it could be seen as bad practice and maybe will put into the function documentation instead what size is expected to be passed. And you are right this error is really misleading. I might report that, if it is not gone in Android Studio 2 which is on the verge of being released.

Comment: @Torge Specifying the array size is not bad practice - it is _good_ practice. It is self-documenting code saying "this function expects an allocated array of exactly 4 items, no more, no less". Out of curiosity, what compiler are you using?

Comment: @Lundin: I guess what ever is packaged in the Android NDK. About good/bad practice. As a defensive coder I just see the pitfalls Ian pointed out. You might end up thinking the size is enforced as well as the fact that `sizeof` will not work as you might expect on it. But I guess this is up to taste after all.

Comment: @Torge Pick GCC if you have an option to pick compiler. If defensive coding is a priority, consider using the intrinsically safe `void testB(size_t size, uint8_t buff[size])`. This is the most safe way to write generic functions, although it is not portable to dinosaur compilers.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks a lot, this is really the solution I was looking for. This also is not leading to an error in the IDE anymore and I can check the input size. I guess the caller still could mess up or lie to me. But I think as the function provider I did everything I could this way. Thanks.

Comment: It may be legal code, but it is terrible code because it gives you the impression that the compiler will prevent calls with arrays of lengths other than 4 which is not true.  In fact, it likely won't even give a warning (gcc, even with -Wall -Wextra won't).  If you want to document it, document it.

Comment: @JohnHascall Professional programmers use static analysers on top of the compiler. The `[4]` would help the static analyser to detect bugs in your code. The compiler's job is not to detect bugs, but to translate source code into binaries. Should it spot some bugs for you by coincidence, then that's just a bonus.

Comment: No, a "Professional Programmer" would write something like `int testB ( uint8_t * buffPtr, size_t buffSize );` and not give the world yet another `gets()`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semicolon after the closing `}`. The compiler just carries on and reports an error some time later when it got confused:

```
void testA() {
    uint8_t buff[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };    // semi-colon here
    testB(buff);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this was just in the example which I wrote out of my head. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as promised I will try to answer this myself using the various information collected in the comments.

**Is the code correct?**

Yes, the code is correct. `uint8_t[4]` will decay into `uint8_t *` and is handled as such by the compiler. (Thanks [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin))

**Is the IDE buggy?**

Yes. The error is at least misleading. It should better be a warning, that the array specification has no effect and is not enforced but decays into `uint8_t *` or as [Ian Abbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264491/ian-abbott) put it:

> If a parameter of a function is declared with array type, C will
>   automatically convert it to a pointer type. This can catch people out,
>   especially if they use the parameter as the operand of the sizeof
>   operator. That will produce the size of a pointer, not the size of an
>   array. (By default, the GNU GCC compiler issues a warning about that.)

Some additional details by [juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza):

> ...sometimes people who are not familiar with the stranger parts of C's
>   syntax think such a function would make a local copy of the array
>   and/or only compile with arrays of the right length. The fact that the
>   function will accept any uint8_t* makes these assumptions dangerous,
>   and the IDE tries to prevent this. I don't allow foo(int a[N]); in my
>   own coding conventions but some people like to have the "hint" as a
>   form of documentation

**How can I get rid of this error?**

Unfortunately Android Studio 1.5.1 seems not to have a configuration for this parameter (at least it can not find the right entry in the inspections list)

But you can change your method signature to either

```
void testB(uint8_t *buff) {
```

Or as [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin) suggested and what I preferred:

```
bool_t testB(size_t buff_len, uint8_t buff[buff_len]) {
    if (buff_len != 4) return false; 

    //code

    return true;
}
```